# How can we refer to the people of Tarsonis?

Tags: starcraft

This may be a question in regards to English grammar:

**I am wondering how people of the planet Tarsonis refer to themselves?**

Is it *Tarsonian*?

Comment: Sure, why not. What makes you doubt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official [Starcraft wikia](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Tarsonis) makes extensive reference to people from Tarsonis being known as "**Tarsonians**";

> After living in isolation for sixty years, **the Tarsonians developed
>   second-generation subwarp engines** which allowed their ships to make
>   contact with Moria and Umoja.
>
> Tarsonis was the most technologically
>   advanced and prosperous of the three colonies, having been given a
>   head start by ATLAS.